# C# incorrect insert float data

Tags: c#

I insert float like in the below code. But it saved incorrectly.
for example, I insert 14.5 or 14,5 it saved 145
please help me

```
string table_no = gbox1.Text.Trim();
string gametime = time_hour.Text.Trim() + ":" + time_minute.Text.Trim();
string localdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
float money = float.Parse(txtbox_1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

try
{
      connection.Open();
      baza("insert into stollar (id, table_no, gametime, localdate,  money) values ('" + txt1.Text + "','" + table_no + "', '" + gametime + "', '" + localdate + "', '" + money + "' )");
      connection.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation for your sql variables! Use parameterized sql instead. Your column types should also be correct and use the native type, not the string representation. The parameters should also use the native values (not string representation) for each value.

Comment: why dont you store numbers as numbers instead of converting at saving and casting at loading ?

Comment: You shouldn't EVER directly inser user input into a SQL statement. Use a parametrized query and pass those values (after some validation) as parameters.

Comment: You're relying on *a lot* of implicit conversion between strings and numerics from two different systems here (C# and SQL).  If the precision of your data matters to you, maintain your data types explicitly.

Comment: Side note: It looks like you might be trying to reuse a SqlConnection instance across methods/classes (who knows). Don't do that either, create and dispose your SqlConnection instances on an as needed basis. Connection pooling is built in for most providers.

Comment: @Igor The question has nothing to do with why you'd use prepared statements. It explicitly asks why the OP is getting the wrong value in the database. The issue may or may not be in the SQL.

Comment: @JustinNiessner yes I said that wwhy it happend& and how can I solve this problem&

Comment: @Liam its not working also

Comment: @David what should I do?

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: For starters, double-check the data types of your database columns.  If something is a numeric type, don't use quotes when inserting data.  If it's not a numeric type, don't expect it to be treated as one.  Additionally, and very importantly, begin using parameterized queries instead of directly concatenating string values into your SQL code.  Not only does this help protect you from SQL injection attacks, but this also gives you more control over the syntax of your SQL and the types of the values being used.

Comment: @David I tried that method but problem dont be solved
`connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into stollar (money) values('" + "@money" + "')", connection);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@money", SqlDbType.Float);
                    command.Parameters["@money"].Value = float.Parse(txtbox_1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();`

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: And what *specifically* was the problem when you tried that?  (At a quick glance, your SQL syntax is wrong and highly over-thought.  It should simply be: `... values (@money) ...`  There's no need to break up the string and you shouldn't enclose parameter names in quotes.)

Comment: `const string sql = @"INSERT INTO stollar (id, money) VALUES (@id,  @money)";
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int){Value = int.Parse(txt1.Text)});
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@money", SqlDbType.Float){Value = float.Parse(txtbox_1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`  I tried this, but problem not solved yet. Noe I insert 0,03 but it added 3.00

Comment: @David look that code please

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: You're trying to insert 2 values into 5 columns, so that SQL command is entirely invalid to begin with.

Comment: @David the other columns I clear but not fix problem

Comment: @David not fix 
`const string sql = @"INSERT INTO stollar (id, money) VALUES (@id, @money)"; using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) { 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int){Value = int.Parse(txt1.Text)}); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@money", SqlDbType.Float){Value = float.Parse(txtbox_1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}); conn.Open(); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }`

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: *Define "not fix"*.  You need to explain the problem.  "It doesn't work" isn't an explanation of what's wrong.

Comment: @David The problem is that although the value I want to add is 0.03, it is registered as 3.

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo: This sounds like a culture setting problem.  What specific value does `float.Parse(txtbox_1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` produce?  What was in `txtbox_1.Text`?  Perhaps you need a *specific* culture instead of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: @David like what? The value in the TextBox is equal to *float* values such as 0.03 or 1.55

Comment: What is the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use string concatenation for your sql variables!** Use parameterized sql instead. Your column types should also be correct and use the native type, not the string representation. The parameters should also use the native values (not string representation) for each parameter.

This is a code fix that most likely can fix your problem **but** you need to change your schema to ensure that you are using native types. This will fix your problem where you are storing a localized string representation of a value instead of the native type. Here are my guesses as to the correct data type.

- `id` - should probably be an int marked with `Identity` if you want the Db to auto generate this. In that case change the schema and do not pass a value in your insert.
- `table_no` - probably a `varchar`, be sure to specify the correct length in the parameter.
- `gametime` - should probably be of type `Time`, pass a TimeSpan to the value
- `localdate` - I recommend `datetime2` but `datetime` could also be used
- `money` - use `decimal` and specify the precision and the scale in your schema. Be sure those match what you set on the parameter.

Adjusted code

```
const string sql = @"INSERT INTO stollar (id, table_no, gametime, localdate,  money) VALUES (@id, @table_no, @gametime, @localdate, @money)";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(/*your connection string from app.config or web.config*/))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int){Value = int.Parse(txt1.Text)});
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@table_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100){Value = gbox1.Text.Trim()});
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@gametime", SqlDbType.Time){Value = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(time_hour.Text.Trim()) * 60 + int.Parse(time_minute.Text.Trim()))});
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@localdate", SqlDbType.DateTime){Value = DateTime.Now});
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@money", SqlDbType.Decimal){Precision = 10, Scale = 2, Value = decimal.Parse(txtbox_1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: @iLLkeeNNemo - `it does not work` is something you hear from a user that does not have a clue how a PC works and what information they need to be providing. You are a programmer and can do better than that. Read through [ask] and update your question accordingly, you should also provide a [mcve].